# how to get notification from server when ever it is on

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

Is there any way to get notification from server whenever it is on?
 my requirement is when ever ActiveMQ is on a piece of code will run automatically

in ActiveMQ is  there is no load on startup

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a publisher in your language of choice that periodically sends a test message to ActiveMQ.
2. Create a subscriber in your language of choice that receives the test messages and notifies you via your mechanism of choice that it has successfully received a test message.

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) broker supports [discovery](http://activemq.apache.org/discovery.html) with [IP multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast).

Applications can use discovery for JMS clients to auto-detect a Message Broker to connect to.

This could also be used to monitor a broker's status, using [Java MultiCast support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a piece of code when the broker is started, you can perhaps base it off either an [embedded Camel route](http://activemq.apache.org/broker-camel-component.html) or broker [interceptor](http://activemq.apache.org/interceptors.html). The idea being that when the broker is started, so will these components and thus allows them to issue whatever sort of notification you require.